# How to set large image in ionic.io -push notification

Tags: android, icons, ionic-framework, push

in ionic push notifications, we can add "icon":"xxxxx" in "android" array to change a new (small) icon path ,

```
var push = new Ionic.Push({
"debug": true,
"pluginConfig": {
 "android": {
   "iconColor": "#343434",
   "icon": "abc"
 }
} 
});
```

where the abc.png is from platform/android/res/drawable folder.

but is there any methods to change the push's large icon? Since, the iconColor is valid but I test lots of times , I cant change the color background to a large image.

anyone can help me.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `image` property to the `android` object which is a string describing either a reference to an image in the `drawables` folder, an asset URI, or a remote URL. Although Ionic Push doesn't list itself as supporting this property, actual testing verifies it.

More information: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#images

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no support for the large icon through the FCM notification message payload.
See https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/84 . The problem is known but the issue is closed.